# Parsing <br> within a <td> element in R

Tags: xml, r, xpath

I'm trying to parse some rather unfortunately written html in R, and I've run into a bit of a roadblock.

The table structure is such that 2 strings I require to be in separate fields are only separated by a 
 tag.

```
<td  align="left"valign="top"><font face="Arial" size="2">Frederick Henry    Bay,  Australia<br>Ansett ANA
```

I need the location and operator to be separated, but can't seem to find a way to do it without getting really hacky. I figure there must be a way to properly parse the HTML in the first place.

So far, I've been parsing as follows

```
# Read and parse HTML file
html.raw = htmlTreeParse(url,useInternal = TRUE)

# Extract HTML.
html.parse = unlist(xpathApply(html.raw, '//td', xmlValue))
```

But this drops the br tag, and forces me to use str_split to split the string according to
    "?<=[a-z]|\))(?=[A-Z]"

But this is unreliable. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this

```
test<-'<html><td  align="left"valign="top"><font face="Arial" size="2">Frederick Henry    Bay,  Australia<br>Ansett ANA</td><td  align="left"valign="top"><font face="Arial" size="2">Liverpool, England<br>Queen BRB</td></html>'

library(XML)
html.raw = htmlTreeParse(test,useInternal = TRUE)
xpathApply(html.raw, '//td', function(x)
    xpathSApply(x,".//text()", xmlValue)
)
```

which returns

```
[[1]]
[1] "Frederick Henry    Bay,  Australia" "Ansett ANA"                        

[[2]]
[1] "Liverpool, England" "Queen BRB"
```

Note that each td is turned into an element in the list, and the list is made up of length-two vectors.

Comment: I think that does it! I've just run a quick test and this seems to return just what I'm looking for. I'm slightly embarrassed to admit how much time I've wasted on this issue.

Comment: Could write last statement as: `xpathApply(html.raw, '//td', xpathSApply, ".//text()", xmlValue)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `getChildrenStrings` function:

```
appHtml <- '<td  align="left"valign="top"><font face="Arial" size="2">Frederick Henry    Bay,  Australia<br>Ansett ANA'
library(XML)
doc <- htmlParse(appHtml)
res <- doc["//td/font", fun = getChildrenStrings]

> res[[1]]
                                text                                   br                                 text 
"Frederick Henry    Bay,  Australia"                                   ""                         "Ansett ANA" 

> lapply(res, function(x) x[names(x) == "text"])
[[1]]
                                text                                 text 
"Frederick Henry    Bay,  Australia"                         "Ansett ANA"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something in the veins of

```
matrix(
  xpathSApply(doc, '//td//text()', xmlValue), 
  ncol = 2, byrow = T)
#      [,1]                                 [,2]        
# [1,] "Frederick Henry    Bay,  Australia" "Ansett ANA"
```